# Как получить доступ к postgres консоли в linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql

Я установил PostgresSQL на linux и когда я пытаюсь войти то получаю:

```
$ psql postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "pavel" does not exist
```

На MacOS у меня была отдельная консоль для postgres которая устанавливалась по умолчанию вместе с базой. Для linux нет такой возможности?

Почему мне не предлагается выбрать роль?

Как мне войти в базу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ psql postgres
```

Означает, что вы хотите авторизоваться с настройками по-умолчанию в *базу* postgres. Не пользователем postgres, а в базу данных под названием postgres. Пользователь указывается явно ключом `-U` либо записывается в переменной окружения [`PGUSER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) либо используется тот, от имени которого открыта консоль. Очевидно `pavel` - это имя вашей учётной записи.

Поэтому при работе от пользователя postgres в базу postgres зайти можно (это не значит что всегда можно будет зайти, можно настроить что и нельзя будет).

```
psql -U postgres postgres
```

Так же на настройках по-умолчанию используется unix-сокет и авторизация `peer` в [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). Т.е. проверяется, что пользователь, от имени которого работает консоль совпадает с именем пользователя в базе. Т.е. указанная выше команда не сработает и выдаст ошибку peer-аутентификации. Понадобится править pg_hba.conf, например, для использования md5 авторизации - с использование пароля.

Если вы хотите часто заходить в консоль суперпользователем, то проще завести пользователя совпадающего с именем в консоли, нежели указывать постоянно пользователя и базу

```
create user pavel with superuser login password 'пароль';
create database pavel owner pavel;
```

После вы сможете заходить просто набрав

```
psql
```

Если же вам не нужна постоянно административная консоль (а зачем она может быть постоянно нужна, если только вы не ДБА?), то уберите `superuser` из создания пользователя. Для редких административных задач вполне достаточно способа авторизации через

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно восстановить пароль на user `postgres`. Для этого в коммандной строке наберите:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Потом

```
\password postgres
```

И присвоиваете пароль. После этого выходите:

```
\q
```

Подробно смотрите [здесь](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/dataadmin/pgGettingStarted/firstconnect.html)

Comment: после выполнения sudo -u postgres psql postgres меня пустило в п базу я поменял поральи вышел но при попытке зайти командой `psql postgres` все равно отвечает role "pavel" does not exist. Почему то postgres считает что что я хочу войти под ролью pavel ...

Comment: Это не поможет. У ТСа peer authentication (он в Linux по умолчанию везде, где мне довелось бывать), который логинится **всегда** под текущим именем пользователя в ОС. Так что зря наставили плюсов.